# Image Upload URL Inconsistency

Tags: resource-urls

My image upload url is [civicrm.files]/persist/contribute/

What is telling [civicrm.files] to go that url?

[image]

Comment: Not that I have an answer for you, I'm just as curious as you are - but it would be helpful to know what version Civi you're running and what CMS.

Comment: @RayWright Wordpress 4.8 and CiviCRM 4.7.22

Answer (score 1):

CiviCRM can have issues resolving symlinks if they exist in the path to CiviCRM codebase or resources (mentioned also [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/21926/149)). Either avoid symlinks in your filesystem layout, or supply CiviCRM with the "real" path for the directory.